# How to set programmatically baseAddress for both client and server?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

Currently `baseAddress` is fixed in the app.config file for both service and client

App.Config for both service and client

```
<host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

Is it possible to it programmatically? Like

```
baseAddress = txtbaseAddress.Text;
```

Or any?

Comment: Does it work for you? ServiceHost myHost = new ServiceHost(typof(myType), baseAddress)?

Comment: @AdilMammadov, This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the base address using the ServiceHost as it is readonly. You have to pass the set of baseAddress to the ServiceHost Constructor or you have to use the configuration file.

Please refer the following links

> 1. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb924492%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
> 2. [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rampo/archive/2008/02/11/how-can-wcf-support-multiple-iis-binding-specified-per-site.aspx)

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
     <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix=”net.tcp://test1.fabrikam.com:8000”/>
        <add prefix=”http://test2.fabrikam.com:9000”/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: There are no examples here of doing this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

While this is a bit late it might be useful for someone else.

Using a custom service host based on the ServiceHostFactoryBase as found here :
[Service Host Factory Base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactorybase(v=vs.100).aspx)

Implementation Example : [Implementing Custom Service Host](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2008/01/08/implementing-and-configuring-quot-servicehostfactorybase-quot.aspx)

Additionally the ServiceHostBase class is abstract and can be utilized to create custom ServiceHost.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: The code of the implementation example seems buggy to me. Why is it assigning `constructorString` to a local variable which is never used. What is `constructorString` use for?